# Re-use NAS-backplate with Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, sata

I have a Synology DS1511+ with a broken motherboard. What remains is a nice box with power supply, fans and a backplate for 5 SATA disks. The backplate (P/N:08-04DX5BP14) has two power connectors and no electronics besides a few elco's.

I was wondering if such a backplate would be usable again, for instance with a Raspberry Pi 4, to build a new NAS.

Is there anyone who can shed a light on this?

Comment: If you google 'homebrew raspberry pi nas' you will find a ton of information, likely more than you'll get from a few answers here on SU.

Comment: This is a specific question about using such a backplate, not about building a NAS with a Raspberry Pi. All "homebrew" solutions I've seen before posting the question, work with external USB drives.